# How to explicitly return `void`?

Tags: flutter, dart

One flutter package has this kind of data requesting workflow:

```dart
final cancelListening = await request(
  query: query,
  onResponse: (response) {
    streamController.add(response);
    cancelListening(); // I need to cancel it here;
  },
);
```

But this way I obviously have the error: `cancelListening can't be referenced before it is declared`. As `request()` returns `Future<void Function()>` I can do this:

```dart
void Function() cancelListening = () {}; 

cancelListening = await request(
...
```

And I got `Omit type annotations for local variables.dart(omit_local_variable_types)`.

So, I write this way:

```dart
var cancelListening = () {}
cancelListening = await request(
...
```

But now `cancelListening` is `Null Function()` and I'm getting `A value of type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Null Function()'.`

So my questions is:

1. Is there is a way to explicitly return void in dart? Something like `() => Void()`;
2. Should I simply ignore this linter rule or there is better way to handle this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to setup an intermediary function to call the received callback. `VoidCallback` should be a type for functions that specifically return void, instead of null.

```
VoidCallback? cancelListening;

void stopListening() {
  cancelListening?.call();
}

void listen() async {
  cancelListening = await request(
    query: query,
    onResponse: (response) {
      streamController.add(response);
      stopListening();
    },
  );
}
```

Optionally, instead of making `cancelListening` nullable, you could use the `late` keyword.

```
late VoidCallback cancelListening;

void stopListening() {
  cancelListening(); // No optional operator `?` needed.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. No need to setup an intermediary function: `late void Function() _cancelListening;` and `onResponse: () { _cancelListening.call();` will work fine.

Comment: Good point, I just added something about 'late', but still through the intermediary function. I guess it works without if you use 'late'.

Comment: without `late`: `void Function()? _cancelListening;` and `onResponse: () { _cancelListening?.call();`